# firebase-functions:hosting gives error: time to go build something extraordinary

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I can deploy files through only hosting which works fine
but I try it with firebase functions it says :

```
Welcome
Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

OPEN HOSTING DOCUMENTATION
```

my `index.js` Code goes here :-

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    // // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
    // // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
    //
     exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
     });
```

link to my project:-

```
https://influence-cbc3f.firebaseapp.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deploy functions then use this:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: Ok i did it , i did it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular 6, instead of providing "**dist**" at the following step:

> ? what do you want to use as public directory

You will need to provide “**dist/your_application_name**”

Check out this excellent article 
https://medium.com/@longboardcreator/deploying-angular-6-applications-to-firebase-hosting-b5dacde9c772

Comment: very old issue , i am not using angular , i was using nodejs at that time